# Replace element of a string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I need to convert all uppercase letters to lowercase and vice-versa. If one of the elements of the string is not a valid letter of the alphabet, it must be replaced with “*bug here!*”. Using user-defined function

```
Input: evEry1
Output: EVeRY*bug here!*
```

I am already able to convert all uppercase letters to lowercase and vice-versa. I was also able to change nonalphanumeric elements to a single character but cannot replace it with the entire string "*bug here!*". I end up having error saying it cannot be converted

```
string flip (string w, int t){
    string ch = "*bug here!*";
    for (int j=0; j<w.length(); j++){
        if (w[j] >= 'A' && w[j] <= 'Z')
            w[j] = w[j] + 32;
        else if (w[j] >= 'a' && w[j] <= 'z')
            w[j] = w[j] - 32;
        else 
            w[j] = ch;
    }
    return w;
}
```

Comment: A character is not a string and a string is not a character. So you can not replace characters with strings by using `w[j] = ch;`. Instead you should use the string `replace` method.

Comment: Why does the function have `int t` as a parameter?

Comment: Use standard functions from <cctype> to check & convert characters.
https://godbolt.org/z/Efqvdreeq

Comment: A matter of style: instead of `+ 32`, use `- 'A' + 'a'`. Or, better, `tolower()`.

Answer (score 1):

A character is not a string and a string is not a character. So you can not replace characters with strings by using `w[j] = ch;`. Instead you should use the string [replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) method. Something like this

```
string flip (string w, int t){
    string ch = "*bug here!*";
    for (int j=0; j<w.length(); j++){
        if (w[j] >= 'A' && w[j] <= 'Z'){
            w[j] = w[j] + 32;
        }
        else if (w[j] >= 'a' && w[j] <= 'z') {
            w[j] = w[j] - 32;
        }
        else {
           w.replace(j, 1, ch);  // replace the character
           j += ch.length() - 1; // advance j so we don't process the replacement string
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

Note that after inserting the replacement string we have to increment `j` otherwise we'll start processing the replacement string.

This is untested code.

BTW given the confusion over strings vs characters, you really should change the name of the variable `ch`. How about `str` instead?

BTW I'm not seeing what the purpose of `t` is in the function above. It's not being used so it could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

When you index the string you are looking at a single character, so

```
w[j] = w[j] - 32;
```

is ok.

When you want to insert a substring, you need to use [std::string's insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) function:

```
w.insert(j, ch);
```

This will allocate the extra space needed since you have a string not a single character. You then need to skip `j` ahead by `ch.length()` to move to the next original character.